# How to delete special character in linux

Tags: linux, unix, rm

By mistake I made a file with the name `\`. How do you delete something like that? I've tried `rm --\ rm "\" rm -- -\`and nothing seems to work. I bet it's so simple but I'm stumbled - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's a single character, just a backslash.

try:

`rm -- \\`

Also, at worst, use tab completion. bash/zsh will put in escape characters where necessary.

Comment: thanks man. How could I be so stupid lol I knew it was simple. thanks I got it